# how do I compute the margin-left of an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there a way to write a javascript function that given any HTML element tells me its 'margin-left' in pixels. *(I guess whatever the algorithm then, it can be re-apploed to get margin-right,top and bottom)*

One solution is this:

```
function(htmlElement) {
    return htmlElement.style.marginLeft;
}
```

but that only works if the marginLeft was applied on that html element.

How can I compute it if it was not explicitly set ? 
and if it was not explicitly set in pixels ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj99U/)

```
window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue("margin-left");
```

So `elem.style.marginLeft` gets the CSS value that is applied, `getComputedStyle` gets the actual computed value after everything is applied.

`getComputedStyle` doesn't work in IE8, there are a bunch of polyfills available though:

- [Polyfills-for-IE8 / getComputedStyle.js](https://github.com/jonathantneal/Polyfills-for-IE8/blob/master/getComputedStyle.js)
- [A simpler polyfill](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/)

Comment: Amazing I did not know anything about getComputedStyle thanks I will check this out